# Python - Attribute Error - str' object has no attribute 'studentsinTeam'

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a program where it allows the user to add existing students to an existing team. When I try to do this, it produces **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'studentsinTeam'**. Im not entirely sure how to fix this.

```
class Student: 

  def __init__(self, student_name, form_class):
    self.student_name = student_name 
    self.form_class = form_class
    self.studentTeamlist = []

  def addtoTeam(self, team):
    if self.student_name not in team.studentsinTeam:
      team.studentsinTeam.append(self.student_name)
      self.studentTeamlist.append(team)

class Team: 


  def __init__(self, team, coach):
    self.team = team
    self.coach = coach
    self.studentsinTeam = []

class AddtoTeamScreen: 
  def __init__(self):


    ###This forms the Window for this Screen###
    self.screen2 = tk.Tk()
    self.screen2.title("Add Student to Team")
    self.screen2.geometry("700x400")
    self.getName2 = tk.StringVar()
    self.getTeam = tk.StringVar()
    ###Main Heading######
    screen2H = tk.Label(self.screen2, text = "Add Student to Team", font=("Arial", 25))
    screen2H.pack()
    ####Student Name######
    StudentNLabel = tk.Label(self.screen2, text="Student Name: ")
    StudentNLabel.pack()

    student_entry = tk.Entry(self.screen2, textvariable = self.getName2)
    student_entry.pack()


    ####Combo Box for Team Selection#####

    TeamNLabel = tk.Label(self.screen2, text= "Team: ")
    TeamNLabel.pack()

    teamcb = ttk.Combobox(self.screen2, values= allTeamlist, height = 2, textvariable = self.getTeam)
    teamcb.pack()

    ATbutton = tk.Button(self.screen2, text = "Add Student", command= self.pressed2)
    ATbutton.pack()

    self.BCKBttn = tk.Button(self.screen2, text = "Back to Main Menu", command= self.back2)
    self.BCKBttn.pack()

  def back2(self):
    mainscreen = MainScreen()
    self.screen2.destroy()

  def pressed2(self):
    addName2 = self.getName2.get()
    joinTeam = self.getTeam.get()

    for s,t in itertools.product(allStudentlist, allTeamlist):
      if s.student_name == addName2 and t.team == joinTeam:
        if joinTeam not in s.studentTeamlist:
          s.addtoTeam(joinTeam) 
          messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Successful! ADDED")
        elif joinTeam in s.studentTeamlist:
          messagebox.showerror("Error", "Student Already in Team")
```

How do I resolve this error?

EDIT: Updated code with self.getTeam = tk.StringVar()

Comment: Looks like 'joinTeam' variable is of type 'str', you can add 'print(type(joinTeam))' to confirm this and see why it is returning 'str' instead of 'Team'.

Comment: Could you provide code where self.getTeam is initialized? Looks like self.getTeam.get() returns a string instead of a Team class object

Comment: @YakovlevDenis Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you get joinTeam variable from outside and it is a string. 
So before using it as a Team object, you have to find this object. And you already did it in `if s.student_name == addName2 and t.team == joinTeam:` so now t - is a team object for team with joinTeam name. Just change:

```
s.addtoTeam(joinTeam)
```

to

```
s.addtoTeam(t)
```